# Simple form builder checkbox collection custom html input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

With simple_form_for, how should one go about building something like a color selector? Imagine a page where the user can pick a number of colors to work with by checking checkboxes. I would like to present a little box with the color in it and a checkbox next to it so the user can pick the color by checking the check box. Something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colors[test]"><div style="background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px"></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="colors[test]"><div style="background-color: green; width: 20px; height: 20px""></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="colors[test]"><div style="background-color: blue; width: 20px; height: 20px""></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the html tags to the collection and define classes for each of them. And then style them accordingly. I am assuming you have a `simple_form_for @color` or something similar.

```
<%= f.input :test, :label => 'Choose a Color:', :collection =>{'<div class="red colorbox"></div>'.html_safe => 'red', '<div class="green colorbox"></div>'.html_safe => 'green', '<div class="blue colorbox"></div>'.html_safe => 'blue' }, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

In your stylesheet:

```
/* The colorbox will be under a label with collection_check_boxes class.*/
.collection_check_boxes {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.colorbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.red {background: red;}
.green {background: green;}
.blue {background: blue;}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems a little messy to me with simple_form.  Doesn't seem as simple :). Now, I also have the requirement that I have to group the colors into sections. So something like "Colors.all.in_groups_of(4, false)" is how it should be organized. Putting it in collection doesn't seem to help with that can it? Everything in the collection is treated uniformly?

Comment: What do you mean by grouping? Do you mean 4 checkboxes in each row or something else?

Comment: Right...4 checkboxes in one row.

Comment: Though I am not getting any idea right now, but you can try adding line-break. e.g. `:collection =>{'<div class="red colorbox"></div>'.html_safe => 'red', '<div class="green colorbox"></div><br/>'.html_safe => 'green', '<div class="blue colorbox"></div>'.html_safe => 'blue' }`. Added `<br/>` after green.

Comment: Thanks so much again! Unfortunately, that isn't possible in my situation because I don't know how many colors I will get from an external feed system. I could get 10, I could get 20. I have to group into 4 and warp with a div so I can style it.